# How to parse numeric type date in D3

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, format

All:

If unfortunately I need to part a numeric date like

```
var dt = {date: 20150101}
```

(I do not have access to control how the data generated, so I have to accept that the date is not a string type)

**I wonder how can I parse the date into a Date object in D3?**

I tried using  **d3.time.format("%YYYY%mm%dd")**, but it seems not work.

Thanks

Comment: You need `d3.time.format("%Y%m%d")`.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff  Thanks, but when I use your solution like: var fmt = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d"); fmt.parse(20150101);  it show an error "string.substring is not a function"

Comment: Oh your date is actually a number and not a string -- convert it to a string before parsing (e.g. `"" + d.date`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)?

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
format(new Date(20150101));
```

Comment: thanks, but when I run format(new Date(20150101)); it gave me "1969-12-31"

Comment: @Kuan yeah, what are you looking for? Drop in the [millisecond value](http://www.2ality.com/2014/02/time-values.html) to that format function to convert it to a string. For example `format(new Date(1432180800000))` = "2015-05-21"